# Even number check without: if

Tags: python, numbers

Is there way to check an for even numbers in a list without using : if?

Here what I have when I use if:

```
import numbers

numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,
           16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]

def even_list(numbers):
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
    #while i !=(i / 2):
        print(i)
return i

numbers = even_list(numbers)
```

Now logically this make sense but I dont know any other way other than if.
As you can see I tried using while in there and the program kept on looping 1 when ran.
Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Comment: Well, `i` can never equal `i/2`. So that's why it keeps looping.

Comment: Technically speaking, there is no way other than `if`, because even if you use list comprehension, there will be an if in it: `[x for x in numbers if x%2 == 0]`, or if you use filter, there's a conditional, which is nothing but an implied if: `filter(lambda x: x%2 == 0, numbers)`

Comment: Why do you not want to use if? I would check out [this question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8403/python-check-if-number-is-divisible-by-2-program)

Comment: It might just be the formatting but your return isn't within your `def`.

Comment: Being relatively new to python I wanted to try a concept that a college counselor brought to my attention. Thanks for your input!

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of logic you are using, but as squiguy said, `i` will never be `i/2` so it will be stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use two lists, one for evens and one for odds:

```
evens = []
odds = []
out = [evens,odds]
for elem in numbers:
    out[elem%2].append(elem)

print evens
```

or you could end with:

```
for even in evens:
    print even
```

to simulate the same style of outputting that you have currently.

Comment: this does a better job of avoiding implicit ifs :) +1

Answer (score 2):

ummm

```
def even(numbers):
   return filter(lambda n:n%2==0,numbers)
```

or numpy

```
import numpy
a = numpy.arange(100)
print a[a%2==0]
```

or set manipulation (I think the *only* one that doesnt use a conditional ... but you need to understand sets or you may not get expected behavior, or it may not work with your dataset)

```
def evens(numbers):
    all_evens = set(range(0,max(numbers),2)
    return all_evens.intersection(numbers)
```

an alternative check for  even-ness is

```
not my_test_number&1
```

(I suspect this check is faster than `i%2`, but not sure)

Comment: I'm sure there are lots of implicit `if`s involved with the set solution too.

Comment: probably right :) theres just no conditionals in the actual statement may have been a better phrasing  ...